# Add Manual Formulas in Power BI Table Visualization

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Is it possible to perform calculations based off of the Table Visualization's values? I understand Power BI has the option manually add columns in the data set but that will not work in this example because of how the data is aggregated.

Basically, I would want the option to create a formula next to revenue where I would divide revenue by cost.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6spo.png)

Comment: Read about Measures: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-measures

Comment: @Will, if my answer solves your problem would you mind marking it as the accepted solution and upvoting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been mentioned, a **measure** would be the solution. Something like the following

```
Measure = DIVIDE(CALCULATE(MAX(Table[Revenue])), CALCULATE(MAX(Table[Cost])), 0)
```